# hover not working onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave React. Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

New to React. I am trying to implement a color change for a button when the cursor hovers over the button using React. When I run my app locally, hovering seems to have no effect. Sometimes I receive a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" fatal error when loading the app as well. I believe I have set up the code correctly, but obviously, this is not the case. Any help would be appreciated!

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        hover: false
    }
}

    handleHover() {

    this.setState({
        hover: !this.state.hover
    })
}

   render(){

   var buttonStyle = {

        borderRadius: '5px',
        borderColor: 'red',
        marginTop: 25,

    }


   if(this.state.hover){

        buttonStyle = {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            color: 'yellow'
        }
    }
    else{

        buttonStyle = {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            color: 'orange'
        }

    }


 }

 return(
     <button style={buttonStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleHover()} onMouseLeave={this.handleHover()} type="button" className="btn btn-outline">Learn More</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: You may already know that and just be interested in playing with React events, but It would be significantly more efficient to accomplish this with CSS's `:hover` pseudo selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two changes. First in your button element, you need to pass your hove handler function like this(without brackets)

```
<button style={buttonStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} onMouseLeave={this.handleHover} type="button" className="btn btn-outline">Learn More</button>
```

And you need to bind your hover handler function to the class in constructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        hover: false
    }
    this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about the binding.